# Kafka Consumer subscription vs. assigned partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka is confusing me. I am running it local with standard values.
only auto create topic turned on. 1 partition, 1 node, everything local and simple.
If it write

```
consumer.subscribe("test_topic");
consumer.poll(10);
```

It simply won't work and never finds any data.
If I instead assign a partition like

```
consumer.assign(new TopicPartition("test_topic",0));
```

and check the position I sit at 995. and now can poll and receive all the data my producer put in.

What is it that I don't understand about subscriptions? I don't need multiple consumers each handling only a part of the data. My consumer needs to get all the data of a certain topic. Why does the standard subscription approach not work for me that is shown in all the tutorials?
I do understand that partitions are for load balancing consumers. I don't understand what I do wrong with the subscription.

```
consumer config properties
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "postproc-" + EnvUtils.getAppInst()); // jeder ist eine eigene gruppe -> kriegt alles
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
    KafkaConsumer<Long, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<Long, byte[]>(props);

producer config
 props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 2);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("linger.ms", 5000);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 1024 * 1024 * 10); // 10mb
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
        return new KafkaProducer(props);

producer execution
try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
            event.writeDelimitedTo(out);
            for (long a = 10; a<20;a++){
                long rand=new Random(a).nextLong();
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("test_topic",rand ,out.toByteArray()));
            }
            producer.flush();
        }catch (IOException e){
```

consumer execution

```
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test_topic"));
ConsumerRecords<Long,byte[]> records = consumer.poll(10);
for (ConsumerRecord<Long,byte[]> r :records){ ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve the issue. The problem were the timeouts. When polling I didn't give it enough time to complete. I assume assigning a partition just is a lot faster and therefore completed timely. The standard subscription poll takes longer. Never actually finished and did not commit.
At least I think that was the problem. With longer timeouts it works.

Comment: Which specific timeout was the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing this property I think

```
auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

> What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current
>   offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data
>   has been deleted):
>
> - earliest: automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
> - latest: automatically reset the offset to the latest offset
> - none:    throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for    the consumer's group
> - anything else: throw exception to the consumer.

Reference: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#highlevelconsumerapi